# How to append contents of multiple files to one target file using loop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to append contents of multiple files to one target file using a loop. Below is my code. Every time it overrides the file instead of appending.

```
File[] directoryArr = new File[4];  

directoryArr[0] = new File("...file path");
directoryArr[1] = new File("...file path");
directoryArr[2] = new File("...file path");
directoryArr[3] = new File("...file path");


File[] ListOfFiles = null;

for(int count = 0; count < directoryArr.length; count++)    
    ListOfFiles = directoryArr[count].listFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and add all the Arrays of files to it.

```
List<File[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int count = 0; count < directoryArr.length; count++)
{
        myList.add(directoryArr[count].listFiles());
}
```

Another option would be to have a multi-dimensional array where each element of `ListOfFiles` can store another file array, However, I wouldn't advise taking that path.

Comment: OP is not expecting a `ArrayList`. He asked _How to **append contents** of multiple files **to one target file** ..._

Answer (score 1):

Solution updated:
So:

```
File[] directoryArr = new File[4];
directoryArr[0] = new File("...file path");
directoryArr[1] = new File("...file path");
directoryArr[2] = new File("...file path");
directoryArr[3] = new File("...file path");

List<File> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int count=0;count<directoryArr.length;count++){
    myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(directoryArr[count].listFiles()));
}

File out = new File("file-path.out");
out.createNewFile();
BufferedWriter os = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));
for(File f : myList) {
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
        os.write(line);
        os.write("\n");
    }
    os.flush();
    is.close();
}
os.close();
```

Code not tested, but compile. Solution could be similar.

Comment: OP is not expecting a `File[]`. He asked _How to **append contents** of multiple files **to one target file** ..._

Comment: Yes, but because code, I understood other thing. He is not reading the content of files so... Let see what say @Shashi. Thanks for your point.

Comment: OP seems clear. His code is just _a preparation of list of files to read from_.

Comment: Solution fails if at least one file has  no LF at EOF

Comment: I've tested with empty files, text files with last line without LF and it works. File without EOF are very rare, SO set it. I only have to add write("\n") to not lose end of line. And could be improve if @Shashi want works with binary files.